# How do I store text user enters into pop-up text-field into a NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextfield, uialertview

Some of my `ViewController.h`

```
NSString *title1;
NSString *sub1;
@interface MapMain : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *setter;
}
```

All within the same `ViewController.m`

```
-(IBAction)Write:(id)sender
{
    [self alertView];
}

-(void)alertView
{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                 message:@"Your Info"
                                                 delegate:self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];


    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
    UITextField * alertTextField1 = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    alertTextField1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    alertTextField1.placeholder = @"Name";

    UITextField * alertTextField2 = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
    alertTextField2.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    alertTextField2.placeholder = @"Username";
    alertTextField2.secureTextEntry = NO;

    [alert show];
}
```

So this code correctly makes a pop up appear with two text fields when I click on a specific button. How can I store the text the user inputs when they press the "Done" button into my `NSString *title1` and `NSString *sub1` respectfully, so that I can use the string values when other buttons are pressed later. And how can I make my program not store the text when the user presses the "Cancel" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `MapMain` class conform to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol

```
@interface MapMain : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

and then implement the delegate's method for when the alert is dismissed like this

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) //only if cancel is not clicked (done is clicked)
    {
         UITextField * alertTextField1 = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
         UITextField * alertTextField2 = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
         //... do whatever else you need to here like
         title1 = alertTextField1.text;
    }
}
```